# Identifying the types of parameters passed to methods using the AST of the JDT

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, visitor-pattern

I am using the AST of the JDT to parse Java files and am currently trying to figure out how to identify the type of the parameters passed to methods during method invocation.

Currently I use the VariableDeclarationFragment to store the type of any variable in a method in a HashMap.  When a method invocation occurs (identified using MethodInvocation),  I search for the variable passed as a parameter in the HashMap so as to determine its type.

So for example if I have something like:

```
   int x = 7;
   M1(x);
```

in the HashMap I store x which maps to int.  When the method M1 is invoked I check what is the type of x and use it as needed.

My problem is that this does not work in invocations like

```
   M1(7)
```

Is there a way of determining the type of '7' using the AST?

Comment: Yes.  Read the Java standard. It will tell you the rules.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. You call resolveTypeBindings() on the arguments passed.

Comment: My idea would be to check the type of the argument expression, if it's [NumberLiteral](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FNumberLiteral.html) the you have encountered a number.

Comment: Yes that is a good idea! Thanks @Katona

Comment: I am searching for similar thing; I want to find out the type of the argument passed in method invocation. The argument being passed may not be a local/class level variable which I can look into whole stuff using VariableDeclarationFragment. In my case this argument is again an argument of (public) method of this class!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comments you have to use `resolveTypeBindings()`.

```
M1(7)
```

Will be represented as:

```
ExpressionStatement [655, 6]
    EXPRESSION
        MethodInvocation [655, 5]
            > (Expression) type binding: void
            > method binding: Main.M1(int)
            ResolvedTypeInferredFromExpectedType: false
            Boxing: false; Unboxing: false
            ConstantExpressionValue: null
            EXPRESSION: null
            TYPE_ARGUMENTS (0)
            NAME
            ARGUMENTS (1)
                NumberLiteral [658, 1]
                    > (Expression) type binding: int
                    Boxing: false; Unboxing: false
                    ConstantExpressionValue: 7
                    TOKEN: '7'
```

So by having `ExpressionStatement` you will find out that it has `Expression` which is `MethodInvocation` then you can get its arguments and it will be `NumberLiteral` and then you can use `resolveTypeBindings()`

Note: in comments you were told to check if it's `NumberLiteral` and assume that it's number. Yes this is true it's a number but you won't know its type; whether it's `int` or `double` or something else.

P.S. The tree representation above was made using [ASTView plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/) which is extremely helpful working with AST, so I recommend to get it if you don't have it already.

Comment: I frequently use the ASTView plug-in but never managed to work with resolveTypeBindings().  Worked around this by creating a visit method which takes a node of type VariableDeclarationFragment.

Comment: @gracey yeah you can use visitor pattern to collect `VariableDeclarationFragment`'s but it has nothing to do with `resolveTypeBinding()`, you can always do that regardless resolving or not resolving, so not sure what you mean.